# Expected Expression C

Tags: c

I'm currently developing a code for university which rounds a number, but without using math library in c.

Here's what I did:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double arrd(double x, int n);

int main()
{
    double value;
    int n;
    printf("Insert a value: ")
    scanf("%lf", &value);
    printf("Insert n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n)


    printf ("%f", arrd( value, n));
    return 0;
}

double arrd(double x, int n){
   double r = x;
   double s = 1;
   int e = 0;
   while (e != (n+1)){ /*This is to get to the last number before rounding*/
    s= s * 10;
    r = r*10 - int(r); /*This is where is giving me the error*/
    e++;
   };
   r=r*10;
   if (r<5){
    return x-r*(1/s);
   } else {
    return x-r*(1/s)+(10/s);
   }

}
```

It says that is expecting expression, in r = r*10 - int(r). What should I do?
I'm new to programming, but if there's anything wrong with the rest of the code where I can improve, let me know.

Thanks

Comment: To explicitly convert a value to a different type, the syntax is `(type)value`. In your case you want `(int)r` (not `int(r)`).

Comment: Yes of course! Thank you very much!

Comment: the posted code does not compile!.  The compiler outputs several ERROR messages and some warning messages.   Please correct.  One of the errors is on this statement: `scanf("%d", &n)` which is missing the trailing semicolon ';'

Comment: OT: regarding: `#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>`  There is absolutely no need to include a header file more than once.  Infact header files (include the system headers) have 'include guards' so their contents will only be included once, regardless of how many times there is a `#include` statement for a header

Comment: OT: indenting of the code is for human readability.  an indent of 2 spaces will be hidden when using variable width fonts.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%d", &n)` and `scanf("%lf", &value);`  Always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  I.E.  `if( scanf("%lf", &value) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed\n" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
int(r)
```

Is not valid syntax to cast a value to an `int`.  It is done as follows:

```
(int)r
```

Comment: Note that C++ supports the `int(r)` notation, or at least it did once upon a while ago (say C++98); it may have been deprecated, but I doubt if it has been removed yet.  C has never supported that notation, though.